# Django-shop on Openshift

Tags: pip, openshift, django-shop

I try install Django-Shop on Openshift. In Openshift i created application with django, mysql. Problem is dependencies that demand pip then install django-shop. Second, I don't know how install pip's package - on server or local repo. I install django-shop on my local repo and push that changes on server with help git. Server refused work with change.

Answer (score 0):

You must install dependencies using pip on server. If you install in localhost, it is not installed to git folder.
So login to openhsift `rhc ssh appname` and when logged in, use `pip install django-shop`. Or add `django-shop` to setup.py file.